# jQuery.hide() not working after form submit

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I am trying to get a form working where I want to hide the optional fields if JS is enabled. So I have the following lines in there.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#anfrageFormularOptionalContainer').hide();
    });
```

When I first get on the Page, everything works fine. The Optional Container is set to "display:none;". But when I now submit the form, the Optional Container is showen but its css is set to "display:none;". So why is it still shown? I realy have no idea why this strange thing occurs.

Comment: The ID is too short, only ID's over one hundre characters long will be hidden after a form submit.

Comment: Don't mix Jquery hide() with CSS display.

Comment: @bobthyasian - why not ?

Comment: could you please add the other relevant code? Start with the form submit, do you send the form using ajax? Or does the page refreshes?

Comment: @adeneo wut? you mean dom elements with an id attribute? I think i misunderstand you... The length of the id attribute does not matter at all, and should not matter

Comment: @adeneo Leads to conflicting issues.

Comment: @giorgio there is no other relevant code

Comment: you probably have a rule which overrides your "display:none". You need to post your code or a link to the project

Comment: @bobthyasian i dont mix any css whit the js, because if js is disabled in the browser i want to show the form by default, but not if js is enabled.

Comment: The real question is, does the page reload or not, as that code only runs on page load, and did you check the DOM inspector for the current inline styles, or are you just saying it has display:none somewhere in a stylesheet ?

Comment: @Matanya I ensure you that there is no other relevant code on the site.
Just to say it again, the js is also working but the browser is still showing it. I looked in firebug and the element (id: #anfrageFormularOptionalContainer) has the "display:none;".

Comment: @adeneo YES the site refreshes, again, no other relevant code in there. That means no ajax calls or anything. its just a form and the jQuery.hide() funktion.

Comment: @ThomasVenturini you are not being very helpful... there IS other relevant code, because any other code will help us in seeing the context. The snippet you posted as such is normal and working code, so there must be something else.

Comment: @ThomasVenturini please create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) for us

Comment: What is the form's `action`? Does it cause the same page to be re-served or a different page? If it is the same page, then does something happen server-side occur in response to the form data, which causes the page to be re-served differently?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot it goes to the same site and i also give back the data to the fields if there was an error, so the user can change the fields with the wrong data. AND THANKS! I THINK YOU GOT THE WRITE IDEA! :) ... if i don't give the data back it seams to work.

Comment: @all LIKE I SAID NO RELEVANT CODE. You can trust me in this ;) If there would be more code to know I had given you a jsfiddle right away :)
BUT I HAVE TO ADMIT, I was not realy helpfull, but thanks to every one so far!

Comment: Thomas, mmmmm, not a whole answer yet but possibly along the right lines, as you say. On the surface, `$('#anfrageFormularOptionalContainer').hide();` *should* hide the element again when the page is re-served. Presumably, the js still exists and the element hasn't undergone a change of ID in the re-served page?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot the element and js is still there. i will post the answer when i got it. I think i will have it soon :)

Again, THX 2 everyone!

Answer (score 0):

OK, for everyone, this was a error that occoured by the way i used modx. so i have to do it otherways.

It was not an error of the JS so the answer does not belong here.

THANKS TO EVERYONE ANYWAY!!! You have been very patient with me so thanks a lot!